# How to convert BorderPane into Image

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a BorderPane with many components. Is there a way to convert the BorderPane into Image and store in into ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

JavaFX `Node` has a `snapshot` API. [See a simple example here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-snapshot-as-png-image/), and [a more complex example here](http://java-buddy.blogspot.ro/2012/12/take-snapshot-of-scene-with-javafx.html).

**Related StackOverflow questions:**

[Take a snapshot part of canvas in javaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067936/take-a-snapshot-part-of-canvas-in-javafx)

[JavaFX: multiple snapshots in single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634689/javafx-multiple-snapshots-in-single-image)

[Terrible Screenshot JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132860/terrible-screenshot-javafx)

[Taking a screenshot of a scene or a portion of a scene in JavaFx 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024498/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-scene-or-a-portion-of-a-scene-in-javafx-2-2)